# Why doesn't array_rand work when I request only one item?

Tags: php, arrays, random, key, echo

The following works properly:

```
<?php
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
?>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<?php
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
?>
```

Why isn't `array_rand` working when I request only one random index?

Comment: In the future, please post the error message you're getting. It's not very useful when you tell is something "doesn't work". We need to know *what is happening*, whether's it's crashing or displaying an error or returning something unexpected.

Answer (score 6):

From the manual:

> If you are picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry. Otherwise, it returns an array of keys for the random entries.

Therefore:

- When only getting a single random entry, you just use `$input[$rand_key]`.
- When getting multiple random entries, you use `$input[$rand_key[0]]` (or other index up to the number of random keys pulled)

Answer (score 3):

From [php docs](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php):

> If you are picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry. Otherwise, it returns an array of keys for the random entries. This is done so that you can pick random keys as well as values out of the array.

In your second example you only want 1 random, so it doesnt return an array.

Answer (score 2):

If you read [the documentation](http://php.net/array_rand), it states that if you request only one item, it returns the index, if you request more than that, it returns an array of indices.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input);
echo $input[$rand_keys] . "<br>";
?>
```

this is the true code that will return only 1 result of the array .

Comment: While this is true, but it doesn't really answer the question about how OP asking on why `array_rand` doesn't work on request to only one random index

Comment: because array_rand doesn't work for 1 result only if we use random index logically when you want 1 result you don't need to put all of the random indexes because you only want 1 result so you just do like what I did in the code this is if you want one result if you want multiple results use random indexes hope this is clear for you now .